# Express fast speed or someone arriving early

Tags: kanji

I've seen two writings of this on Duolingo and Jisho. Either as 速い or 早い. I believe both are read as はやい, but which of the two is more relevant in expressing how fast something is or how early someone arrives?

I can imagine 速{はや}い used in a sentence like this, 電車{でんしや}は速{はや}いです or Trains are fast.

Comment: Thanks for the link, this a duplicate. Are both kanji read as はやい?

Comment: Yes they both are read hayai.